# Eclipse Error:Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse

I am using MyEclipse 8.6 for development.
I am facing this issues in eclipse while developing.

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org/eclipse/ui/internal/SaveableHelper
```

Here below is the full stack strace :

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: org/eclipse/ui/internal/SaveableHelper
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveAction.updateState(SaveAction.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.BaseSaveAction.partActivated(BaseSaveAction.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList$1.run(PartListenerList.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList.fireEvent(PartListenerList.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList.firePartActivated(PartListenerList.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.firePartActivated(PartService.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.setActivePart(PartService.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPartService.updateActivePart(WWinPartService.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPartService.access$0(WWinPartService.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPartService$WWinListener.partDeactivated(WWinPartService.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2$4.run(PartListenerList2.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2.fireEvent(PartListenerList2.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartListenerList2.firePartDeactivated(PartListenerList2.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.firePartDeactivated(PartService.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.setActivePart(PartService.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPagePartList.fireActivePartChanged(WorkbenchPagePartList.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartList.setActivePart(PartList.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setActivePart(WorkbenchPage.java:3531)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.requestActivation(WorkbenchPage.java:3071)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.requestActivation(PartPane.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.handleEvent(PartPane.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1027)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1008)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1404)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2269)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:3989)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1578)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2010)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4632)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4632)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2406)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4632)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2406)
```

I also tried it by changing the metadata folder of the workspace but it is not working.

Comment: Sanjay did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @destruor no...Started using eclipse j2ee with plugins.